# Bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys so i am trying to replicate some navbars in bootstrap to get the hang of things.

Right now i am trying to make the same navbar as this [Example](https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/59019.html)

However i cant seem to centre my links in the middle as the same, not sure how to go about doing this, i pulled the logo to the left and the icons to the right, but the text i am not sure about

HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand">
                    <img id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" src="Images/a.png" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Classes <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
           <a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
           <a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
                </form>


            </div><!-- navbar collapse end -->
        </div><!-- container-fluid end -->
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    min-height: 175px;
    background-color: #121314;
    min-height: 175px;
}
```

Comment: bootstrap v3 or v4?

Comment: bootstrap v3 , i had no idea there was v4 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st add `text-align: center;`  navbar container `bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` so the child element will align to center,

2nd for the ul, set it to `display: inline-block;` so it does not take the whole row (block)

3rd from bootstrap css, `.navbar-nav` set to `float: left` to overwrite it use `float: none !important;`

ALSO if you try to get the search bar working, take a look at this one maybe: https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/nmtnkjx5/

```css
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav {
  float: none !important;
}

#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1>ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">
        <img id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" src="Images/a.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Classes <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
      </form>


    </div>
    <!-- navbar collapse end -->
  </div>
  <!-- container-fluid end -->
</nav>
```

Comment: This is perfect, i just wanted to ask those, with the image on the left hand side, how do we get it to be reposive? so when it shrinks it will shrink with the navbar? i know on there site it actually goes ontop

Comment: @RonTheOld Cool, I never resize the logo, usually, it is a fixed size. But try this might give you some idea, note use !important to overwrite some bootstrap css : https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/1mpqdpv4/